# INNER JOIN within UPDATE OUTPUT in one t-sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need to INNER JOIN a resultset returned by UPDATE OUTPUT with another table and return results. Is it possible?

Here is a small example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers]
(   
   [CustomerId] [int],   
   [CustomerName]  [nvarchar](50)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders]
(   
   [OrderId] [int],   
   [OrderName]  [nvarchar](50)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerOrders]
(   
   [CustomerId] [int],   
   [OrderId]  [int]
)
GO

INSERT INTO CustomerOrders (CustomerId, OrderId) VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO CustomerOrders (CustomerId, OrderId) VALUES (1, 2)
INSERT INTO CustomerOrders (CustomerId, OrderId) VALUES (2, 1)
GO
```

Need to update OrderId on CustomerOrders table and return names of the customers, all in 1 shot. So far I can only return CustomerIds:

```
UPDATE CustomerOrders SET OrderId=NULL 
OUTPUT Deleted.CustomerId
WHERE OrderId='1'
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

TSQL/SQL Server 2005+ supports JOINs in the UPDATE clause - see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx):

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERORDERS
   SET orderid = NULL
OUTPUT c.customername
  FROM CUSTOMERORDERS co
  JOIN CUSTOMERS c ON c.customerid = co.customerid
```